# Problema con redirección en .htaccess, conflicto con redirecciones

Tags: .htaccess, redirección

Tengo estas dos redirecciones en el fichero .htaccess, que cada una quiero que lleve a una nueva página diferente:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/listado/categorias/productos$ https://www.nuevaweb.com/productos/

RedirectMatch 301 ^/listado/categorias/productos?filter_id_categoria=1&filter_id_producto=1$ https://www.nuevaweb.com/productos-nuevos/
```

La primera redirección la hace correctamente, pero la segunda no funciona, parece haber un conflicto porque la raíz de la url es la misma (listado/categorias/productos) pero no sé cómo puedo solucionar esto...

¿Cómo redireccionar ambas urls a distintas webs y evitar este conflicto?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el contenido completo de las reglas? Parece que no tienes una parada puesta allá donde la necesitas.

Comment: Eso es lo que tengo, no tengo nada más incluido en esas reglas. La primera sí que funciona pero la segunda no está funcionando. Gracias

Comment: Disculpa, estaba pensando en `mod_rewrite` y no en `mod_alias` (que es lo que estás usando). Espero que mi respuesta resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Estoy usando mod_rewrite, gracias!

Comment: En tu segundo re-direccionamiento con parámetros debes reutilizarlos en la nueva re-dirección?

Comment: No, no hace falta reutilizarlos. Simplemente que lleve a una nueva web similar a la que pongo de ejemplo :) gracias

Comment: ¿Qué tal lo llevas @Norak ? ¿Pudiste probar los cambios que te propuse?

Comment: Funciona a la perfección @OscarGarcia!! Lo he probado y has solucionado mi problema. Además muy bien explicado y muy completo. Te lo agradezco mucho :)

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto [`RedirectMatch` de `mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) como [`RewriteRule` de `mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) no permiten patrones que contengan la cadena de búsqueda GET (todo aquello que hay más allá del separador de URL `?`).

Por suerte la última permite hacer uso de [la variable de servidor `%{QUERY_STRING}` con `RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
# Activamos mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Aquí nos evitamos comprobar que sea un archivo (agrego comprobación
# para detectar también directorio) en cada conjunto de reglas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

# Coincidencia EXACTA de lo que haya tras el ?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_id_categoria=1&filter_id_producto=1$
# Coincidencia EXACTA en la URL (sin el / inicial)
RewriteRule ^listado/categorias/productos$ https://www.nuevaweb.com/productos-nuevos/ [QSD,L]

# Coincidencia EXACTA con una consulta vacía tras el ?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
# Coincidencia EXACTA con la misma ruta
RewriteRule ^listado/categorias/productos$ https://www.nuevaweb.com/productos/ [QSD,L]
```

Las reglas incluyen las siguientes banderas:

- `qsdiscard|QSD`: Descartar cadena de consulta. Todo aquello que va tras el separador de URL `?` se descarta y no se mantiene en la nueva URL.
- `last|L`: Última regla. Tras hacer efectiva la regla de redirección actual se detiene el proceso y no se comprueban las siguientes.

URLs probadas en el entorno de prueba:

- http://localhost/listado/categorias/productos?filter_id_categoria=1&filter_id_producto=1
- http://localhost/listado/categorias/productos

Comment: Acabo de probar lo que me indicas. Agradezco tu ayudar pero no me está funcionando. No sé si hay alguna manera alternativa de resolver esto...

Comment: Sí, usando `mod_rewrite`. Editaré mi respuesta cuando pueda para ponerte un ejemplo.

Comment: Ya he estado haciendo pruebas. Lo que te he puesto en mi respuesta es cierto (el orden de los `RedirectMatch` debe ser el correcto) pero haciendo pruebas me he dado cuenta que no es posible hacer uso de los parámetros GET para las reglas, sólo la componente del nombre de la ruta ([pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname)), no de la búsqueda ([search](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search)).

Comment: Por lo pronto `mod_rewrite` tampoco lo permite, pero al menos tienes acceso a macros que contienen los datos de la consulta para construir las reglas. Redactando.